# how to update a table attribute each time a user logs back in? (rails 3 + omniauth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have a column in my User table called "image"

This image stores the URL of the avatar that is pulled from a user's twitter account.

Part of User table

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "image"
  end
```

I am using omniauth to allow users to authenticate using twitter, deauthenticate, reauthenticate, etc.

After they deauthenticate and try to reauthenticate is when I want to verify that the avatar is matching on my site. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
class AuthenticationsController < InheritedResources::Base
 def create
  omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
  if authentication
     user = User.find(authentication.user_id)
     sign_in_and_redirect user
  else current_user
   token = omniauth['credentials']['token']
   secret = omniauth['credentials']['secret']
   current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'], :token => token, :secret => secret)
   current_user.update_attribute(:image => omniauth['info']['image'])
   flash[:success] = "Authentication successful"
   sign_in_and_redirect current_user
  end
 end
```

It's basically this line when they try to reauthenticate

```
current_user.update_attribute(:image => omniauth['info']['image'])
```

But I am getting errors. This particular code above gave me `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`.
I tried other ways but I got `undefined method update_attribute`. Anyone know how I can update the "image" column inside the user table using data from twitter + omniauth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the syntax of [`update_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attribute), it takes 2 parameters `name` and `value`

```
current_user.update_attribute(:image, omniauth['info']['image'])
```

Futhermore, I'm pretty sure the avatar url in twitter never changes: it always shows the user's current avatar. So you don't need to update it in your DB, just use it directly in your page to get the latest user's avatar.